# How to redirect request to subfolder and mask url on Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Say my site's root url is `xyz.com`.
I have the website content sorted year-wise, and I want the users to be redirected to `xyz.com/2015`. But the URL a user sees should remain `xyz.com`.

The subfolder thing is just for internal use. And all files are in the subfolder itself. How do i do it? Most of the answers on web did not work for me. (I also have a index.php in root is that why?)

My current config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/subfolder [L,P]
```

Comment: No, index file is not the problem. you can rewrite your homepage to /2015

Comment: @Starkeen how exactly?

Comment: Do you have access to the server configuration? Just change your DocumentRoot.

Comment: You need to post the code you tried   before we can help you.

Comment: @covener yes i have access to .htaccess

Comment: "server configuration" is the opposite of htaccess.  htaccess is a supplemental way to configure things when you don't have access to the servers configuration file.

Comment: @covener I'm on shared hosting, so do not have access to OS level configuration. Only cpanel access.